# Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [3080, 770]

Tags: data-science, linear-regression, data-fitting

Below are the x_train and y_train numbers :

**x_train.shape -->  (296, 770)
y_train.shape -->  (3080,)**

I tried to transpose the x_train and reshape as well.
**x_train.reshape(-1,1)**

When i try the fit model I am getting this error.
Below is the error message I get:
Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [227920, 3080]

any suggestion on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Well, that's the size of your data. The number of y-values does not match  with the input matrix. What do you want to do? Where does the data come from?

Comment: I am trying to do a fit for Linear regression model

Comment: Well, yes. In most cases, however, you have some input value that results in an output value via some function. The number of input values, hence, should matches the number of output values. In your case it does not. Why is that?